# Find the first string between two substrings in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to find the first occurrence of a string between two substrings in a large string in python, and I'm getting some unexpected behavior. Here's an example:

```
import re
str = 'STUFF start STUFF I CARE ABOUT end STUFF end STUFF end'
regex = re.compile('start.*end',re.DOTALL)
stufficareabout = regex.search(str)
print(stufficareabout.group())
```

I'm expecting to get 'start STUFF I CARE ABOUT end' as a result, but I'm instead getting 'STUFF start STUFF I CARE ABOUT end STUFF end STUFF end'. I thought regex.search returns the first match it finds, which to me would mean it would stop after the first "end" match, not keep going until the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` with `".*?"`:

```
import re
a, *_ = re.findall('start.*?end', 'STUFF start STUFF I CARE ABOUT end STUFF end STUFF end')
```

Output:

```
'start STUFF I CARE ABOUT end'
```

Comment: Umm just wondering, why did you answer this duplicate question when you could've used your dupe hammer to close the question as exact dupe?

Comment: @abccd I think any connection between the OP's question and the problem proposed in the prospective duplicate is vague at best.